# Model change event order in backbone js

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

Is it guaranteed that 'change:property' events are always fired *before* 'change' events?
Here is an example:

```
MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    property1: 'value1',
    property2: 'value2'
});

var myModel = new MyModel();
myModel.bind('change:property1', function () { alert("change pty1"); })
       .bind('change', function () { alert("change"); })
       .bind('change:property2', function () { alert("change pty2"); });
```

Is it guaranteed that the function bound to 'change' will be fired last?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: yes

Looking at the source code, yes the `individual:changes` are fired in the loop, and after that, if there was any change, the main `change` event will fire. None of these will fire if you passed `silent: true`.

The order of the individual change events firing depends on the order of the attributes passed to `.set()`.

Comment: thank you for digging into backbone's source! I'm wondering if this is an implementation detail or a design choice. I don't want to rely on an impl detail. Wondering why this isn't properly documented.

Comment: There are many other problems with backbone as well, such as mostly redundant underscore dependancy. I actually I rewrote my own implementation of the whole thing( took like 6 hours which includes many new features) so I was already familiar with the source :)

Comment: nice :) did you open source it? the _ dependency is ok for me as I use the _ template engine.

Comment: Haven't had the time to document it at all and it might have some bugs as I haven't used it for very long. The documentation would be required to use it as the templating engine is self made as well, and the usage differs slightly from backbone (there is no need to bind any change events for example). I can still put the full source somewhere for you to look at if you are interested.

Comment: I am curious to see how you did. I'll definitely have a look if you open-source it. I'm not going to use it in production though :)