# Backbone change trigger is never called

Tags: backbone.js, eventtrigger

I'm trying some backbone.js examples and can't get change triggers to work. The "Welcome to this world" alert shows up as expected, but "Changed my name to" is never shown. Debugging the code with firefox reveils the same result, a breakpoint on the second alert is never hit.

Any ideas what's wrong?

This is my code:

main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>hello-backbonejs</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.6/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>

    <script src="model.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

model.js

```
Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: 'Fetus',
        age: 0
    },
    initialize: function(){
        alert("Welcome to this world");
        this.on("change:name", function(model){
            var name = model.get("name"); // 'Stewie Griffin'
            alert("Changed my name to " + name );
        });
    }
});

var person = new Person({ name: "Thomas", age: 67});
person.set({name: 'Stewie Griffin'}); // This triggers a change and will alert()
```

Comment: take a look at this question:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915352/model-change-event-order-in-backbone-js][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915352/model-change-event-order-in-backbone-js

Comment: Version 0.3.3 doesn't have `on`, it used `bind`. Newer versions of Backbone use `on` to match jQuery. Upgrade to the latest version of Backbone and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the correct version of the js libraries I had to change main.html into this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>hello-backbonejs</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.2/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js"></script>

    <script src="model.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```